# How do I access others photonView for RPC?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc, multiplayer, photon

I began coding in c# only a week ago so sorry if any questions are easily solvable.

I'm trying to make a multiplayer game of tag, and so far tagging works. What I'm dealing with is trying to reset the game so it can restart. I'm counting the amount of tagged players by using the players PhotonView with Tag.Length

Variables

`private GameObject[] UnTaggedPlayers;`
`public PhotonView Player;`

Code

```
    public void OnTagged()
    {
        //Flag as tagged
        _isTagged = true;
        //Touchbacks countdown
        _touchbackCountDown = _touchBackDuration;
       
        GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().material = _InfectionMat;
       

        tagged.Play();

        Player.tag = "Tagged";
    }

    [PunRPC]
    public void OnUnTagged()
    {
  
        //Flag as tagged
        _isTagged = false;
        //Change the color of player

        GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().material = _initialMat;
        GetComponentInChildren<SkinnedMeshRenderer>().material.color = _initialColor;

        Player.tag = "NotTagged";
    }
   
    public void Update()
    {
        UnTaggedPlayers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("NotTagged");

        if (photonView.IsMine)
        {
            if (_touchbackCountDown > 0f)
            {
                _touchbackCountDown -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }



    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        {

            var otherPlayer = other.GetComponentInParent<TagManager>();
            if (otherPlayer != null)
                if (_isTagged && _touchbackCountDown <= 0f)
                {
                    if(UnTaggedPlayers.Length <= 0)
                    {
                        //Untag Everyone
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        otherPlayer.photonView.RPC("OnTagged", RpcTarget.AllBufferedViaServer);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I'm trying to fill in the part with //Untag everyone, But I'm unsure how to do so. I was trying to find a way to find everyones photonView and send it an RPC to untag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PunRPC is a good idea.
You could declare a `List<PhotonView> playerList` and add all the instantiated players.
With this list with all the photonViews of all the players, just scroll down the list and invoke the RPC method for each one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.Length; i++)
    playerList.RPC("OnTagged", RpcTarget.AllBufferedViaServer);
```

Alternatively, other players could also be registered in a static list to save resources, which would be filled by all players.
To call your function on all it would be enough to call the "UntagEvryPlayer ()" RPC method on your player.
The called method can simply go through the static list of players and call the OnUnTagged () method on each one locally.
It would have the advantage that instead of calling the RPC method on all the photoViews and thus creating many calls, exponentially with respect to the number of players, with the second solution you would send the RPC event only with your photonView and the other remote clients would call the local method.
If you need more help just ask :)